# how to count value from 2 condition (2 column) using PHP function count from 1 table (Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

From Database

```
ID   Name Department position
================================
1    A    MK          IT
2    B    MK          RD
3    C    MK          EN
4    D    BD          IT
5    E    BD          RD
6    F    BD          EN
7    G    BD          IT
8    H    OB          IT  
9    I    MK          EN
```

how to write the code to display in table as following this

display something like this in the table

```
position/departmet    MK  BD   OB
===================================
IT                    1    2   1    
RD                    1    1   0   
EN                    2    1   0
```

i just confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it by using `CASE`,

```
SELECT position,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'MK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MK,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'BD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BD,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'OB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OB            
FROM tableName
GROUP BY position
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9529d/1)

Or use `Prepared Statement` if you have unknown number of columns

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when Department = ''',
      Department,
      ''' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS ',
      Department
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT position, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tableName 
                   GROUP BY position');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## [SQLfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b74c20/1)

Comment: i have edit my q, the code will be the same or not, thank u

Comment: the second query will still work,

Comment: one more q     SELECT position, <---we can put "IT", "RD", "EN" instead right
        SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'MK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MK,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'BD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BD,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'OB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OB            
FROM tableName
GROUP BY position

Comment: no, `MySQL` doesn't have builtin `PIVOT`, I guess you need to use the second query.